# Custom AWS WorkMail Filtering

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-workmail

Is there a way to apply email work flow rules (bounce / drop) to emails received by AWS WorkMail based on content in the subject / body?

Wanting to filter all emails with an empty body or subject to spam, as well as filtering on some phrases.

**Note**: The documentation says you can't use lambda https://docs.aws.amazon.com/workmail/latest/adminguide/lambda.html

> The Lambda function does not affect the sending or receiving of email.

**Note 2**: The receiver rules don't cover these use cases either https://docs.aws.amazon.com/workmail/latest/adminguide/email-flows.html#email-flows-patterns

> An email flow rule can apply to a specific email address, or all email addresses under a specific domain or set of domains.